# Grafana Cloud - Anonymous Access - Embed iframe

Tags: iframe, grafana

This question relates to **Grafana Cloud** and **not** a locally-installed instance of Grafana.

I wish to embed a Grafana dashboard and/or panel as an iframe in a public website.  This needs to be a *live* panel, not a snapshot of historic data.

The Grafana Cloud UI allows sharing of panels - and in fact automatically generates the relevant iframe code, but advises:

> The html code below can be pasted and included in another web page. **Unless anonymous access is enabled, the user viewing that page need to be signed into grafana for the graph to load.**

In a local instance of Grafana, I would allow *anonymous access* by editing the `grafana.ini` file.  However, that does not appear to be an option in Grafana Cloud.

There are a number of unanswered questions similar to mine on the Grafana community page.  Is this possible?  Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Bottom line, I want to embed my **Grafana Cloud** dashboards in a public website.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana Cloud is the `Software as a service` (SaaS) solution and it supports only selected number of customizations: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/support/customizing/

`anonymous access` is not there -> it is not supported -> you can't use it as you want.

Use different deployment model, which will fit better your specific needs. Of course Grafana team can offer you more suitable model, but that will cost you more than generic Grafana Cloud instance.